# how to add incremental values to elements i'm creating in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I want to make sure the option elements I'm creating in this function have values 0,1,2,3,4….. so they match the index number. I'm just not sure how to do that in the for loop.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks

```
function receiveAnswer(response) {
  var aSeats = document.getElementById("aSeats");
  while (aSeats.childNodes.length > 0) { // clear it out
    aSeats.removeChild(aSeats.childNodes[0]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < response.aSeats.length; i++) { // add the items back in
    var option = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.aSeats[i]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just making sure you set `option.value` to "i"?

```
  for (var i = 0; i < response.aSeats.length; i++) { // add the items back in
    var option = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.aSeats[i]));
    option.value = i;
    // you need a line here to add the option to the <select> element ...
  }
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want to do but I'm a javascript noob so I have no clue how to do that properly

Comment: wow is there a that was easy button somewhere??? thanks a lot. I'm sure you think i'm dense but thanks a ton for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an option for a select with the `Option` constructor:
`new Option( text, value )`

```
function receiveAnswer(response){
    var sel = document.getElementById('aSeats');
    // clear all current options
    sel.length = 0;
    // add new options
    for( var i = 0; i < response.aSeats.length; i++ ) {
        var opt = new Option( response.aSeats[i], i );
        sel.appendChild( opt );
    }
}
```